# dynamoDB complaining about primary key in FilterExpression

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

### Problem

I'm getting the following error after performing a Query to my DynamoDB instance:

```
Query failed: Validation Error: Filter Expression can only contain non-primary key attributes: Primary key attribute: baked_date_and_baker_uuid
```

The problem is I'm positive I'm not using any key of the selected GSI in my query.

### Context

I have two GSI with the following schemas

```json
{
       "IndexName": "cake_index",
       "KeySchema": [
           {"AttributeName": "cake_uuid", "KeyType": "HASH"},
           {"AttributeName": "baked_date_and_baker_uuid","KeyType": "RANGE",},
       ],
       "Projection": {"ProjectionType": "ALL"},
},
{
       "IndexName": "kutchen_index",
       "KeySchema": [
           {"AttributeName": "kutchen_uuid", "KeyType": "HASH"},
           {"AttributeName": "baked_date_and_baker_uuid","KeyType": "RANGE",},
       ],
       "Projection": {"ProjectionType": "ALL"},
}
```

And doing the following query with boto3

```py
def get_dessert_data(
    dessert_uuid: str,
    dessert_type: str,
    before_than: datetime,
    after_than: datetime,
    starting_token: Optional[Dict]
):
  filters = None
  # Select appropiate GSI partition_key 
  if dessert_type == "cake": 
      index_name = "cake_index"
      gsi_key = "cake_uuid"
    elif dessert_type == "kutchen":
      index_name = "kutchen_index"
      gsi_key = "kutchen_uuid"
    else:
      # Handle error

  # Process conditions to apply to sort key
  if before_than is not None and after_than is not None:
    parsed_before = parse_date_into_gis_format(before_than)
    parsed_after = parse_date_into_utc_string(after_than)
    conditions &= Key("baked_date_and_baker_uuid").lte(f"{parsed_before}")
    filters = Attr("created").gte(parsed_after) # <= Only time using filters and it's not a GSI key

  elif before_than is not None:
    parsed_datetime = parse_date_into_gis_format(before_than)
    conditions &= Key("baked_date_and_baker_uuid").lte(f"{parsed_datetime}")

  elif after_than is not None:
    parsed_datetime = parse_date_into_gis_format((after_than)
    conditions &= Key("baked_date_and_baker_uuid").gte(f"{parsed_datetime}")
  
  # Finally generate the token for pagination, passing primary key for the table and the GSI.
  if starting_token is not None:
    starting_token = {
        "table_partition_key": starting_token["table_partition_key"],
        "table_sort_key": starting_token["table_sort_key"],
        gsi_key: dessert_uuid,
        "baked_date_and_baker_uuid": starting_token["baked_date_and_baker_uuid"],
    }
  pagination_conf = {
    "MaxItems": 10,
    "PageSize": 5,
    "ExclusiveStartKey": starting_token
  }
  paginate_kwargs = dict(
    TableName="yummies",
    IndexName=index_name,
    KeyConditionExpression=conditions,
    ScanIndexForward=not reverse,
    PaginationConfig=pagination_conf,
  )
    if filters is not None:
      paginate_kwargs["FilterExpression"] = filters

  # return pagination with paginate_kwargs
```

### More information

The error does not appears consistently, in fact is "new" as of today.
We managed to get the error again by running the raw DynamoDB query obtained from logs.
I'm fairly sure it's not related to the pagination configuration.

According to [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=172530),

> To clarify, are you doing a query on your GSI, instead of your base
> table? If so, the error message will make sense because
> QueryFilter/FilterExpression doesn’t allow hash and range keys, **so if
> you are querying the GSI it won’t allow FilterExpression on your GSI
> hash or range keys**.

I've re-checked that the filter expression is not using any key fields from the selected GSI.

So what's causing the error? And why is singling out `baked_date_and_baker_uuid` as an element in `FilterExpression`?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in your code. If it says you've specified a field in your filter, then you (or something in between that code and the actual aws api call) have specified that field somehow.